# VBA implementing a better script with minimal editing

Tags: vba

This script is used on a laser machine to put date on product and letter associated with month/year. There Is a cycle in the code that needs to be followed. I have tried doing this code on an online VB compiler and get nothing but errors. I do want to note this code does work in the software used to put the Key code on the product. Q and I needed to be omitted from the code and yes I do know there is an I in the code for 2001 it is wrong. There is 2 cycle for the months Current Cycle is 2 and on Jan 2020 it will be cycle 1 again which means Jan-Dec 2020 will now be letter N-Z omitting I and Q. (CORRECTION Nov 17 2019) Jan 2020 will start with A-M not N-Z omitting I.

```
        Project.ProcessActiveItem
        Document.Show
        Project.UpdateViews
End Sub

strWeekday = "%d"
strMOnth = Month(Now)
strYear = Year(Now)

If strMOnth = "1" Then strMOnthLetter = "N" End If
If strMOnth = "2" Then strMOnthLetter = "O" End If
If strMOnth = "3" Then strMOnthLetter = "P" End If
If strMOnth = "4" Then strMOnthLetter = "R" End If
If strMOnth = "5" Then strMOnthLetter = "S" End If
If strMOnth = "6" Then strMOnthLetter = "T" End If
If strMOnth = "7" Then strMOnthLetter = "U" End If
If strMOnth = "8" Then strMOnthLetter = "V" End If
If strMOnth = "9" Then strMOnthLetter = "W" End If
If strMOnth = "10" Then strMOnthLetter = "X" End If
If strMOnth = "11" Then strMOnthLetter = "Y" End If
If strMOnth = "12" Then strMOnthLetter = "Z" End If

If strYear = "1996" Then strYearLetter = "D" End If
If strYear = "1997" Then strYearLetter = "E" End If
If strYear = "1998" Then strYearLetter = "F" End If
If strYear = "1999" Then strYearLetter = "G" End If
If strYear = "2000" Then strYearLetter = "H" End If
If strYear = "2001" Then strYearLetter = "I" End If
If strYear = "2002" Then strYearLetter = "J" End If
If strYear = "2003" Then strYearLetter = "K" End If
If strYear = "2004" Then strYearLetter = "M" End If
If strYear = "2005" Then strYearLetter = "N" End If
If strYear = "2006" Then strYearLetter = "O" End If
If strYear = "2007" Then strYearLetter = "P" End If
If strYear = "2008" Then strYearLetter = "R" End If
If strYear = "2009" Then strYearLetter = "S" End If
If strYear = "2010" Then strYearLetter = "T" End If
If strYear = "2011" Then strYearLetter = "U" End If
If strYear = "2012" Then strYearLetter = "V" End If
If strYear = "2013" Then strYearLetter = "W" End If
If strYear = "2014" Then strYearLetter = "X" End If
If strYear = "2015" Then strYearLetter = "Y" End If
If strYear = "2016" Then strYearLetter = "Z" End If
If strYear = "2017" Then strYearLetter = "A" End If
If strYear = "2018" Then strYearLetter = "B" End If
If strYear = "2019" Then strYearLetter = "C" End If

Set YWWS1 = Document.CreateString(5)
YWWS1.Text = strWeekday & strMOnthLetter & strYearLetter
YWWS1.Update

Set YWWS2 = Document.CreateString(6)
YWWS2.Text = strWeekday & strMOnthLetter & strYearLetter
YWWS2.Update


Document.Show
Project.UpdateViews
```

Comment: By "better" do you mean less copy/paste if statements or time-wise? For readability a case statement would look better, but realistically process intensity wise you're not going to see much if any improvement.

Comment: @Mike Pretty much trying to get rid of all the if statements so they don't have to keep adding year by year.

Comment: What does `Document.CreateString()` do. I haven't seen it in VBA before?

Comment: @ja72 I'm not even sure myself. This code was implemented way before me as you can see. All I know is that it works i'm not that great at vba. I do know from me tinkering with it a bit inside the software when you "create a string" it makes a "Text" box that text will be outputted to. That text box gets an ID# so this part of the code here                                                                            Set YWWS1 = Document.CreateString(5)
YWWS1.Text = strWeekday & strMOnthLetter & strYearLetter
YWWS1.Update                will print the correct IF statement to ID#5 text box.

Comment: You forgot the year "2003.5" for letter "L" :-)

Comment: @mike What happen to your answer?

Comment: @lamar249 should show now. its not going to handle the additional pre-reqs noted in your comments to the other answer(months looping instead of static values) at this point, though it should be trivial to perform the same math functions. I personally prefer his method the array based system is more understandable even if the math is still going to be required for either answer.

Comment: @mike thanks for all your help but neither script is no longer needed as of right now, as the software/lasers turn out to be obsolete and is not 100% compatible with W10. So for now they are deciding if should revert back to W7 and remove from the network or stay W10 and buy new lasers and software.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 2017 is our origin point and the general formula for assigning letters and numbers remain constant: ie: 2020 should be `D`

We can convert the difference and remainder in years by 26 to identify at what point of the iteration we're in.

For example 2020 is 3 years after 2017 (well adjust this value by 1 because 2020-2017 is zero base where A-Z starts with 1).

3+1=4 means we should provide `D`.

By using ASCII/CHR conversions we can simply add 64 to our remainder value + 1 to get the letter for that year iteration.

Similar logic is utilized for months, but assuming the codes are constant(with the offset beginning at `N` accounted for by adding 14 to the ASCII value before conversion). If these iterate let me know and we can adjust based on the iteration pattern.

I would update your code to the following:

```
        Project.ProcessActiveItem
        Document.Show
        Project.UpdateViews
End Sub

strWeekday = "%d"
'strYear = year(Now)
'strMonth = Month(Now)

Dim intYear As Integer: intYear = year(Now)
Dim intMonth As Integer: intMonth = Month(Now)
Dim intYearIter As Integer
Dim intMonthIter As Integer

'Get current month and add 14 to align with sequence
    intMonthIter = Month(Now) + 14

'If current month iteration is 17 (Q) skip to next
    If intMonthIter = 17 Then
        intMonthIter = intMonthIter + 1
    End If

    strMonthLetter = Chr(intMonthIter + 64)

'Get iteration of supplied year
    If intYear >= 2017 Then
        intYearIter = (intYear - 2017 + 1) Mod 26
    Else
        intYearIter = 26 - ((2017 - intYear + 1) Mod 26)
    End If

'If iteration is 17(Q) or 9(I) skip to next
    If intYearIter = 17 Or intYearIter = 9 Then
        intYearIter = intYearIter + 1
    End If

    strYearLetter = Chr(intYearIter + 64)

Set YWWS1 = Document.CreateString(5)
YWWS1.Text = strWeekday & strMOnthLetter & strYearLetter
YWWS1.Update

Set YWWS2 = Document.CreateString(6)
YWWS2.Text = strWeekday & strMOnthLetter & strYearLetter
YWWS2.Update


Document.Show
Project.UpdateViews
```

Comment: I'll get back with you next week to see if this will work. I won't be back in office till then. I do want to know if this will omit letters Q & I as they are not used here because they look like 1 and O.

Comment: @lamar249 Edited answer to avoid utilizing Q and I and skipping to next letter. These could be easily dumped into functions to increase readability.

Comment: Thanks! I will let you know Wednesday when I get back if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Replace most of this code with a function that stores the codes in arrays and indexes the arrays based on the current month and year. This way the codes are flexible, as they don't *have* to be sequential and more codes can be added later.

```
Public Function GetDateCode() As String

    Dim strMoLetter() As Variant, strYrLetter() As Variant

    strMoLetter = Array("N", "O", "P", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")
    strYrLetter = Array("D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "M", "N", "O", "P", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C")

    Dim intMo As Long, intYr As Long
    intMo = Month(Now): intYr = Year(Now)

    GetDateCode = "%d" & strMoLetter(intMo - 1) & strYrLetter(intYr - 1996)
End Function
```

<sub>Note that in this case letters "L" and "Q" are missing.</sub>

Now call this function as follows

```
Dim code As String
code = GetDateCode()

Set YWWS1 = Document.CreateString(5)
YWWS1.Text = code
YWWS1.Update

Set YWWS2 = Document.CreateString(6)
YWWS2.Text = code
YWWS2.Update


Document.Show
Project.UpdateViews
```

Comment: If I'm looking at this right this wouldn't work as the strMoLetter only going through the last 12 letters of the alphabet but actually every 2 years it goes through 24 out of 26 letters with I(eye) and Q are omitted. Currently we are in the second half so after Z the strMoLetter will restart at A.

Comment: You can make it work, using the `Mod` function to cycle through indexes.

Comment: https://ibb.co/kqrNdhw Error when trying to run it with this. Realized after uploading it doesn't show the highlighted line which is the Public Function GetDatecode() as string.

Comment: In the screen shot you're missing a `Sub` for the continuation of the code after the function. After the End Function there should be a `Public\Private Sub` indicating the start of the next block of code